# how to calculate distance between two points within the same list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a list named 'cords' with all the x-y coordinates in a list.
[image: List of x, y co-ordinates]
I need to calculate the distance between 1st(x,y) and 2nd(x,y) then 2nd(x,y) and 3rd(x,y) coordinates and so on until the end of the list. The values in the list are in float.

i am using

def find_distance():

```
    for i in range (0, (len(cords))):
        res = [float(ele) for ele in cords[i]]
        dis. append(res)
        for j in range (1, ((len(cords))-1)):
            dist=math.sqrt((cm.dis[i][0] - cm.dis[j][0])**2 + (cm.dis[i][1] - cm.dis[j][1])**2)
            dista. append(dist)
 return res , dista
```

This throws an error that list index is out of range, how can i solve this?

Comment: For a start, please read the descriptios of the tags you applied. They effectively contradict. Further, remove the image and copy'n'paste the text it contains. Also, consider providing a [mcve] extracted from your code. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You should use `zip` as `zip` will iterate till exhaustion of any of the provided list

```
from math import sqrt
points = [(1,2.3), (3.4, 5.6), (2.3, 7.8)]
res = [ sqrt((y[0]-x[0])**2 + (y[1]-x[1])**2) for x,y in zip(points, points[1:]) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. let's say your i=0. now your "dis" has 1 element [x,y] and you
   initiated y to 1.
2. Now you are doing this "cm.dis[i][0] - cm.dis[j][0])**2". here dis[j][0] or
   dis[1][0] doesn't exist
3. all you have at this point is dis[0][1] and   dis[0][1] as "dis" has one
   element [[x,y]]

Comment: Please enclose code in backticks `\`` (or select and press Ctrl+K to format)